# MVC DataTable Issue not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am a newbie to MVC application development. I'm trying to add functionality to a EF table using datatables. I created my table and can access it fine (without any functionality). I followed the instructions found at: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/. In summary here's what I did:

1. I added the following lines to the `<head>` section of _Layout.cshtml

   ```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
   <script type="text/css" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>
   ```
2. Then I assigned an ID to the table on the Index view generated by the MVC controller:

   ```
   <table id="tblServer"class="table">
   ```
3. Finally I added the following block of code at the end of the  tag on _Layout.cshtml

   ```
   <script>
     $('#tblServer').dataTable();
   </script>
   ```
4. I disabled all other references to JQuery so they're not loaded multiple times. I commented out the following sections:

   ```
   @*  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@

    @* @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@
   ```

I'm able to see the table, but no styling is available. No filtering, search functions are available either. Please help.

See screenshot here -
[image: See screenshot here]

Comment: Can you show your code where you're initializing the datatable?

Comment: This is what i used: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblServer').DataTable();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the JQuery library which you have commented out. Also the JQuery library should load before the JQuery.Datatable.js file. Jquery is the dependency for the jquery.datatable.js file.

So you may want to do something like in exact order:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/css" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>
```

Comment: That worked. In addition, I copied the files from CDN to local directories and then relinked on VS. Thanks for the help and sorry for this late reply.